# CoreData Fetch Crashes if used with dispatch_async

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I have a core-data app that runs without crashing if I perform a fetch inside `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
- (void) performCoreDataFetch {
   NSError *error;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performCoreDataFetch];
}
```

The only problem with the above way of performing fetch is if the data to be returned is big, it freezes the app for a few seconds (but does return correct result without crashing every single time), so to avoid that I decided to use dispatch_async (code shown below) and call `[self performCoreDataFetch]` inside it.

But if I run this same [self performCoreDataFetch] inside dispatch_sync **within viewDidLoad**, like shown below,:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self performCoreDataFetch];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
```

Calling `[self performCoreDataFetch]` within dispatch_async crashes the app randomly saying "`-[NSFetchRequest fetchLimit]: message sent to deallocated instance`"

My fetchedResultsController method looks like this:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return  fetchedResultsController;
    }

    // Create and configure a fetch request with the Organization entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Organization" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

    // create sortDescriptor array
    NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nameDescriptor, nil];
    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorArray;

    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;

    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"state LIKE %@", filterByState];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    // Create and initialize the fetchedResultsController
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc ] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"uppercaseFirstLetterOfName" cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // Memory management
    filterByState = nil;
//    [sortDescriptorArray release];
    [nameDescriptor release];
//    [predicate release];
    [request release];
    [aFetchedResultsController release];

    return fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You should not have to call the `performFetch` method yourself...

Comment: Without a performFetch,I don't know of another way  to execute a core data fetch.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you initialize the fetched results controller lazily, the fetch will be done there without you having to call `performFetch` yourself. Again, what are you trying to do with the fetch?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do: If you look inside my fetchedResultsController method, there is a predicate parameter "filterByState". This variable is passed to this UITableViewController via a different tableViewController. Based on that predicate, the data set this fetchedResultsController returns is different every time. Please let me know if this is still unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Core data is not thread safe if you perform a fetch for a fetchedResultsController. It makes sense, as the fetchedResultsController is the datasource of your UI. Rather than perform a fetch, set your fetchedResultsController to `nil` and reload your tableView.

Comment: Are you saying that inside my nsfetchedResultsController method, I should always start by setting the fetchedResultsController to nil?

Comment: No. You set it to `nil` when you need to update your table. The table update will automatically call your `fetchedResultsController` method which will lazily create a new one. (Look at the method and see how it works.)

Answer (score 1):

Core data is not thread save. To be more exact, the NSManagedObjectContext is not save. All NSManagedObject belong to a particular NSManagedObjectContext and they are not interchangeable.

Pre IOS 5 you need to put really really complicated method. Basically each thread require it's own NSManagedContext

After IOS5, you can do:

```
__managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

Then you can do

```
[__managedObjectContext performBlock ^{
    //Some really long operation
}]
```

on any thread that is not main thread.

That will do it on a different thread however in a thread save way. Basically core data will put your operation into queues and it will execute that one by one locking the managedObjectContext for each operation.